# Showing First Row of Elements of Collapsed Region

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Any idea how to show first row of elements inside collapsed region as a default (so that collapse and expand happen on second row and above).

http://jsfiddle.net/3pmzLdrr/

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span4 collapse-group" style="text-align:center">
            <p class="collapse">
                <a class="btn btn-app" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-app" href="#">
                    <i class="fa faa-edit"></i>Edit
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-app" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-app" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-app" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-app" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-app" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-app" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit
                </a>
            </p>
           <p style="text-align:center"><a class="btn" href="#">Display All</a></p>
        </div>
</div>

$('.row .btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $collapse = $this.closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse');
    $collapse.collapse('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Could not understand what you are trying to say. So explain little bit clearly.

Comment: Said that collapse region has three rows. First row never collapse, its always shown. Collapse/expand only happen on second row and next. Sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: What do you mean by "row" here?

Comment: As in the fiddle, I'm creating collection of buttons inside the collapsed region. Buttons will pushed to next row/line if its exceed available width.

Comment: Okay, You need to collapse all the rows/lines that are below the first row/line right?

Comment: Right. Maybe you can check brainly.co.id as a sample. If I shrink the browser width, rows below the first will go to collapsed region.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96205/discussion-between-john-r-and-aries-wandari).